# How can I simply toggle between Cameras if I press a certain key?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so I have 2 cameras set up in my hierarchy in Unity:

[image]

I'd like to know, When in-game, how can I toggle between both cameras when a certain key is pressed? I'm aware I'd maybe need to make a script for this, just not sure how I'd go about doing it.

Comment: This can help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/63221/how-to-set-main-camera.html

Comment: By simply waiting for someone to write the script for you, you wont learn anything. You need to have something. At-least, a simple if statement to read from the keyboard then another simple line of code to change the main camera. Just google "unity change main camera"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple cameras

```
  using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public Camera[] cameras;
private int currentCameraIndex;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    currentCameraIndex = 0;

    //Turn all cameras off, except the first default one
    for (int i=1; i<cameras.Length; i++) 
    {
        cameras[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    //If any cameras were added to the controller, enable the first one
    if (cameras.Length>0)
    {
        cameras [0].gameObject.SetActive (true);
        Debug.Log ("Camera with name: " + cameras [0].GetComponent<Camera>().name + ", is now enabled");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //If the c button is pressed, switch to the next camera
    //Set the camera at the current index to inactive, and set the next one in the array to active
    //When we reach the end of the camera array, move back to the beginning or the array.


}

public void Change()
{
        currentCameraIndex ++;
        Debug.Log ("C button has been pressed. Switching to the next camera");
        if (currentCameraIndex < cameras.Length)
        {
            cameras[currentCameraIndex-1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            cameras[currentCameraIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log ("Camera with name: " + cameras [currentCameraIndex].GetComponent<Camera>().name + ", is now enabled");
        }
        else
        {
            cameras[currentCameraIndex-1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            currentCameraIndex = 0;
            cameras[currentCameraIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log ("Camera with name: " + cameras [currentCameraIndex].GetComponent<Camera>().name + ", is now enabled");
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Extremely basic question, you should go to some c# tutorials.

At any rate, this will do. Put this in the Update method:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        //don't forget to set one as active either in the Start() method
        //or deactivate 1 camera in the Editor before playing
        if (Camera1.active == true)
        {
            Camera1.SetActive(false);
            Camera2.SetActive(true);
        }

        else
        {
            Camera1.SetActive(true);
            Camera2.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```